# UseState array empty itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a website using React.
I have an useState array that holds the response from the server, a list of orders.
The useState feature invokes a component that shows one element of the array at a time, when you click on a button it should remove from array,
every 5 seconds we check if the array is empty, if it is it sends an api request to the server and adds new data to the array.
This is the request

```
setInterval(() => {
        console.log(order.length);
        if (order.length == 0) {
          FindCustomer() //sends an api request
          .then(r => JSON.parse(r))
          .then(
            r => {
              console.log(r, 'r');
              let col = r['col']; //col is the array of orders.
              setOrder(col)
            }
          );
        
      }
    }
      , 5000); // fetch updates every 5 seconds
```

This is the removing from array:

```
const removeOrder = () => {
  console.log(' b4 removed from array', order); //here we see the length of array
  setOrder(order.splice(1));
  console.log('removed from array', order);//always 1, why???
}
```

We tried experimenting with it, but could not figure it out!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing with the removeOrder function is related to how the splice method works and how React's state updates work.
By creating a new array with the elements you want to keep and then updating the state with that new array, you won't run into the issue of order always having a length of 1

```
const removeOrder = () => {
  console.log('Before removed from array', order);  //here we see the length of  array
  const updatedOrders = [...order.slice(1)]; // Create a new array without the first element
  setOrder(updatedOrders); // Update the state 
  console.log('Removed from array', updatedOrders); 
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, `Array.prototype.slice` already returns a new array reference, so there's no need to shallow copy it again into another new array.

Answer (score 1):

you are using splice in wrong way . it removes all the elements from original array from 1st position onward thus leaving only 1 element which was at the 0 position.

```
setOrder(order.splice(1))
```

order will be replaced with the array containing the removed element, and not the array with the first element removed as you might expect.

To correctly remove the first element and update the state, you should use the slice method as mentioned in the previous response:

```
setOrder(order.slice(1));
```